# Embedded Lua Singleton Pattern Linux vs Mingw

Tags: c++, cmake, lua, mingw, swig

I'm working on an embedded Lua project and noticed that the behavior is different if I'm using a native Linux compiler vs the MinGw-w64 Cross Compiler. I'm using Swig to generate the wrapper files, and CMake to build the project (and testing with Wine).

### node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node {
public:
  static Node* GetRoot();
  int GetCount();
  void SetCount(int count);
private:
  static Node *root;
  int count;
};

#endif /* NODE_H */
```

### node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"

Node* Node::GetRoot() {
  return root;
}

int Node::GetCount() {
  return count;
}

void Node::SetCount(int count) {
  this->count = count;
}

Node* Node::root = {new Node()};
```

### node.i

```
%module node

%{
  #include "node.h"
%}

%include "node.h"
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "node.h"

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"  
}
extern "C" int luaopen_node(lua_State* L);

int main() {
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  luaopen_node(L);

  luaL_loadfile(L, "main.lua");
  lua_call(L, 0, 0);
  lua_getglobal(L, "init");
  lua_call(L, 0, 0);

  std::cout << Node::GetRoot()->GetCount() << std::endl;
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(Singleton)

find_package(Lua REQUIRED)

add_executable(singleton main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(singleton nodelib)
target_link_libraries(singleton nodelua)
target_link_libraries(singleton ${LUA_LIBRARIES})

add_library(nodelib SHARED)
target_sources(nodelib PUBLIC
  node.h
  node.cpp)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(UseSWIG)
set_property(SOURCE node.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(nodelua
  TYPE SHARED
  LANGUAGE lua
  SOURCES node.i)
target_include_directories(nodelua PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
swig_link_libraries(nodelua
  PRIVATE
  nodelib
  ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

### main.lua

```
function init()
   local root = node.Node.GetRoot()
   root:SetCount(1)
end
```

Could anyone explain why the output is `1` when compiled natively and `0` when cross compiled with MinGw? How can I get the singleton to properly update when returning from the embedded Lua call?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the issue is that DLLs don't handle static members like this well. Since both the `singleton` executable and the `nodelua` library have a dependency on `nodelib`, they both get their own copy of the static member declared in its header files. Solve this by making `root` a static global in the `node.cpp` file.
(Also make nodelua a static library)